# Compile CPLEX in C++ in Linux: Command line

Tags: c++, cplex

I am a new user of CPLEX C++. I want to compile a C++ program on Linux. I tried the following command line for a C program and it works well. But I cannot compile a C++ program.

The command line which I use:

```
g++ hello.cpp \
  -I/<path>/CPLEX/CPLEX_Studio1261/cplex/include \
  -I<path>/CPLEX/CPLEX_Studio1261/concert/include \
  -L/<path>/CPLEX/CPLEX_Studio1261/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic \
  -L/<path>/CPLEX/CPLEX_Studio1261/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic \
  -lilocplex -lconcert -lcplex -lm -lpthread
```

And errors:

```
In file included from 
    <'path'>/CPLEX/CPLEX_Studio1261/concert/include/ilconcert/iloenv.h:21,
                     error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
    <'path'>/CPLEX/CPLEX_Studio1261/concert/include/ilconcert/ilosys.h:376:21: error: fstream.h: No such file or directory
```

... and many more errors like this.

What should I change in my command to be able compile C++ programs as well?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information about your problem? As it stands, it is answerable, but it's still quite vague. The paths to your files will be quite useful.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't expect to use the same procedures for both.